# Image comparison slider with diagonal handle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I need to make an image comparison slider, the usual slider where you have two images and a handle that allows you to show/hide the images.
Like this one for example https://codyhouse.co/demo/image-comparison-slider/index.html

The twist is that the handle must be vertical, but not perfectly vertical, it must have an angle, like in the image below. Then it's dragged horizontally. How would you achieve this?
[image]

Comment: Do you have any test code or examples that you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/jzeo4xsm/82/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function makeClip(width, height, mid) {
    //left, top
    var half = 50;
    var coords = [
      [0, 0],
      [mid + half, 0],
      [mid - half, height],
      [0, height]
    ];
    return coords;
  }

  function setClipStyle(target, left) {
    var coords = makeClip($(target).width(), $(target).height(), left);
    console.log(coords);
    var parts = [];
    parts.push(coords[0][0] + "px " + coords[0][1] + "px");
    parts.push(coords[1][0] + "px " + coords[1][1] + "px");
    parts.push(coords[2][0] + "px " + coords[2][1] + "px");
    parts.push(coords[3][0] + "px " + coords[3][1] + "px");

    var style = 'polygon(' + parts.join(",") + ')';
    console.log(style);
    $(target).data("mid", left).css("clipPath", style);
  }

  setClipStyle(".img-over img", 300);
  $(".slide-handle").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    containment: [-20,0,580,0],
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      setClipStyle(".img-over img", ui.position.left + 30);
    }
  });
});
```

This manipulates the CSS of the Image with `clip-path`. You will need to check on Browser Compatibility. I also used jQuery UI to make it easier to address Drag operations.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path
- https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/
- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip-path/

Comment: Thanks a lot!It worked perfectly. I put an image as the diagon handle.  https://jsfiddle.net/7kLh5raz/